# How to achieve parallax behind horizontal bars while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I've seen this effect a couple times now, but I can't find a "name" for it - what's it called? What's the basic theory behind this effect? Does it use pure CSS, or is it primarily driven by JS?

Description:

As the user scrolls vertically down the page, the solid background gives way, à la "[curtain reveal](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/reveal-effect)", to a background image. Rather than just reaching the bottom of the page, however, another horizontal bar, moving at the same rate as the previous "solid background", covers up the background image from the bottom. As the user continues to scroll, the solid background again gives way to a background image, but this time the background has changed to some other image. The effect is similar to a magician waving his or her hand in front of an object and the object substantially changing in some way.

Another way to put it is that there are "gaps" in the solid background though which different background images can be seen.

Here's an example I found (after a good bit of searching): http://www.astoriacassis.com/
(*Ignore the "gallery"-style rotating image at the top. Scroll down and notice the picture of the pool and then later a lamp with an elephant on it.*)

Initially I thought it might be something similar to the [parallax effect](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/07/how-to-create-a-simple-parallax-effect/), but it actually appears to be substantially different.

I've seen this effect before and I'd like to know how to replicate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is achieved by exploiting the background attachment property on moving `divs` to create an effect that causes the images to appear to change, while it is in fact two `divs` simply scrolling up the screen.

Check out this CodePen for a demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sCuvI/

The important parts:

HTML

```
<div class="content">
  Lorem Ipsum
</div>
<div id="s1" class="scroll"></div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem Ipsum
</div>
<div id="s2" class="scroll"></div>
```

CSS

```
.scroll
{
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  /*The important part*/
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background: no-repeat center center fixed;
  /*Stretch the background*/
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: No... this does not quite match what I described. Ignore the "gallery"-style image at the top. Scroll down and look at the picture of the pool and then, if you continue scrolling, the lamp with the elephant.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake, I see now what the site is doing. I will update my answer to more correctly mirror the functionality of that site.

Comment: I have updated the example to now match the site you shared. The example may appear a little choppy because the images do not load quickly enough. This can be fixed by preloading the images in a `img` tag in a hidden `div`

Comment: It's a valiant attempt to replicate the effect, but it's still not correct. If you go to the example page and use Chrome's DOM editor to change the height of the "ancre4" div to 50%, you can scroll in such a way that you can see both background images simultaneously. The effect is similar to a [before-and-after slider](http://codepen.io/ace/pen/BqEer), except with two entirely different images.

Comment: Ok. After some extensive DOM, JS, and CSS digging I think I have found the solution. I have updated the solution to reflect the functionality of the site. Thank you for bearing with my missing what you were looking for.

Comment: Wow... thanks... did not expect you to spend so much time on that!

Comment: I don't mind it at all. I learned how this effect works in the process. Nothing is a waste of time if there is knowledge to be gained.

Comment: @ZaneM. actually you don't need to put `background-attachment: fixed` and `fixed` in the background shorthand twice in your code example.